# how can i implement seek bar like circle in android?

Tags: android

I want to implement the seek bar in a circle not in a straight line , and it work like following image .How can i implement this .
Any help will be apprecieted.[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try to look at Android sources for some custom seekbars, take it source and customixe as you want .For instance here is simple guide:

Take sources of circle red timer from standard android clock app.Look here: http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/
Take the latest android version and look for `deskclock` app. There you can find `CircleTimerView` class.Then search for this class dependencies (R constants, Utils, etc.) and customize it as you want.

Some people have already grabbed this idea.You can look e.g. here: https://github.com/JesusM/HoloCircleSeekBar